# How can I create a new dataframe out of a json column in a pyspark dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe where some of the columns are nested json objects, because I created it from a jsonl file. The schema looks like this:

```
root
 |-- _corrupt_record: string (nullable = true)
 |-- meeting: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- meeting_id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- meeting_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- meeting_url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- time: long (nullable = true)
 |-- category: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- city: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- country: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- category_id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- category_lat: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- category_lon: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- category_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- category_state: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- category_topics: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- topic_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- urlkey: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- category_urlname: string (nullable = true)
```

What I need to do is filter on some of the root level columns, and then create a new dataframe from the category_topics struct (this is a json object column). After this I imagine I would have to do a pivot and count in order to see how many times a topic appears. I have not found any examples of how to do this directly with dataframe operations, and I don't want to extract the column as a list and then create a new data frame out of it (unless that's the only possible way)

Any help would be much appreciated.